# Assigning reference of one object to other object in Java?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, reference

I've seen a lot of questions about references to objects, and have partially understood how they work. I still have a few doubts about them though.

Firstly, what do all the words in this statement mean?

`Box b = new Box();`

I know that `new Box()` causes an object to be created and the reference to the object is returned. This reference gets stored in `b` if I'm not wrong. So what's the initial `Box` for? According to what I've read, it's the class which defines Box. I'm not sure though. Which brings me to my next question.

I tried to understand what the initial term means in the statement to I tried this out:

```
class LOL
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Box b=new Box();
        Cup c=new Cup(); 
        Box f=new Cup(); //*****
        f.daa(); //Prints Box.daa
        f.display(); //Prints Cup.display
        f.disp(); //ERROR!
    }
}
class Box
{
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Box.display");
    }
    void daa()
    {
        System.out.println("Box.daa");
    }
}
class Cup extends Box
{
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Cup.display");
    }
    void disp()
    {
        System.out.println("Cup.disp");
    }
}
```

So what is going on here? What does the line ***** actually do? The object created is of type `Cup` (I think) so why can't it call `f.disp()`? Can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: In `Box f = ...`, `Box` is the type of the variable `f`. It means it can store references to anything of type `Box`, and that includes any subtypes.

Comment: "So what's the initial `Box` for?" Java is a statically and strongly typed language. This means: every variable has a type that is known at compile time and you can only assing values of that type (or sub-types, i.e. sub-classes) to this variable. `Box b` say "I want to have a variable named `b` and its (static) type is `Box`". At run time, however, the object referenced by `b` can either be a `Box` or any sub-class of `Box` (e.g., a `Cup` in your example).

Comment: @Turing85 your comment should be an answer

Comment: @AmanThakkar it does not answer your whole question, just a part of it. The rest, I think, is already explained in the answers below and I do not like to repeat information.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes thanks mate. Don't have rep or I'd have upvoted already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Box f = new Cup();` creates a new Cup and stores it in the variable `f` of type `Box`. The code below sees that `f` is of type `Box` and treats it as such. As `Box` does not have a method called `disp()` you can't execute `f.disp()`.

You would have to change `Box f...` to `Cup f...` or cast f to type `Cup` before calling `disp()`.

Comment: Okay so the object is of type Cup but the code below it thinks it's of type Box? So only Box contents are accessible?

Comment: You are very close: the object is of type Cup as well as of type Box, because a Cup is also a Box (Cup is a subclass of Box). The code below only knows that it is a Box object (because it is a Box variable), and can therefore only access Box members

Comment: Ah yes, I get it now. Cleared up! Don't have enough rep to upvote though :p

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, don't worry about the upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand object oriented concepts. Here you need to apply basic inheritance and overriding concepts.

- `Cup` is a sub class of `Box`.
- `Box` has `display()` and `daa()` methods.
- In `Cup` you have overridden `display()` method of `Box`, inherited `daa()` and `disp()` method of `Cup` itself.

```
Box f = new Cup();
```

Here you are creating an object of `Cup` and it is being held in the `Box` type reference, this can be done because `Cup` is a `Box`.

```
f.disp();
```

This gives a compilation error as `disp()` method can not be resolved at compile time as it is not defined in the `Box` class.

Comment: I liked this explanation, thanks. "Because Cup is a Box" made it clear